# How can I produce multiple plots on one graph where each plot has a different color? Can I set a colormap to an array of scalar variables?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colormap

I have a series of simple mass-radius relationships (so a 2d plot) that I'd like to include in one plot according to how well of a fit it is to my data.  I have the radii (x), masses (y), and a separate 1d array that quantifies how well the M-R relationship fits to my data.  This 1d array can be likened to error, but it isn't calculated using a standard Python function (I calculate it myself).

Ideally, my end result is a series of ~2000 mass-radius relationships on one plot, where each mass-radius relationship is color coded according to its agreement with my data.  So something like this, but instead of two colors, it's on a grayscale:  [image: Sample plot]

Here's a snippet of what I'm trying to do but obviously isn't working, as I didn't even define a colormap:

```
for i in range(10):
    plt.plot(x,y,c=error[i])
    plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

And again, I'd like to have each element in `error` correspond to a color in greyscale.

I know this is simple so I'm definitely outing myself as an amateur here, but I really appreciate any help!

EDIT: Here is the code snippet where I made the plot:

```
for i in range(2396):
        if eps[i]==0.:
            plt.plot(f[i,:,1],f[i,:,0],c='g',linewidth=0.1)
        else:
            plt.plot(f[i,:,1],f[i,:,0],c='r',linewidth=0.1)
        plt.xlabel('Radius')
        plt.ylabel('Mass')
        plt.title('Neutron Star Mass-Radius Relationships')
```

Comment: Could you post some python plotting code you have done until now? Assuming that you have a list with x=["values of radius"] with most of the points are from 10 to 16.. and y=["values of mass"] with most of the points between 2 to 3. If you have a category for each of the data points then it can be used to make different colors over the same plot with subsets of datapoints

Comment: Hi Coldy, thanks for the reply.  Because it's a few lines, I've included the code snippet where I make the attached plot as an edit in the original post, but you're exactly right.  In my file, x and y are parts of a 3d array `f` - so `x` is technically `f[0,:,1]` and `y` is `f[0,:,0]` where x (radii, in km) range from ~10-~16, and y (masses, in units of solar mass) range from ~0.3-3.

Answer (score 0):

**You have one fit value for each series of points:**

Here is a script to plot multiple series on a single plot, where each series (i.e. each line) is colored based on a third `fit` variable:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fit = np.random.rand(25)

cmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap('binary')
color_gradients = cmap(fit)           # this line changed! it was incorrect before

fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [30, 1]})

for i,_ in enumerate(fit):
    x = sorted(np.random.randint(100, size=25))
    y = sorted(np.random.randint(100, size=25))    
    ax1.plot(x, y, c=color_gradients[i])

cb  = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax2, cmap=cmap,
                                orientation='vertical',
                                ticks=[0,1])
```

[image]

Now responding to your questions from the comments:

> **How does `fit` play into the rest of the plot?**

`fit` is an array of random decimals between 0 and 1, corresponding to the "error" values for each series:

```
>>>fit
array([0.76458568, 0.15017328, 0.70686393, 0.98885091, 0.18449953,
       0.62506401, 0.49513702, 0.69138913, 0.96844495, 0.48937011,
       0.09878352, 0.68965829, 0.13524182, 0.95419698, 0.39844843,
       0.63095159, 0.95933663, 0.00693236, 0.98212815, 0.16262205,
       0.26274884, 0.56880703, 0.68233984, 0.18304883, 0.66759496])
```

`fit` is used to generate the divisions of the color gradient in these lines:

```
cmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap('binary')
color_gradients = cmap(fit)
```

I'm not sure where the specific documentation for this is, but basically, passing an array of numbers to the `cmap` will return an array of RGBA color values spaced accordingly to the array passed:

```
>>>color_gradients
array([[0.23529412, 0.23529412, 0.23529412, 1.        ],
       [0.85098039, 0.85098039, 0.85098039, 1.        ],
       [0.29411765, 0.29411765, 0.29411765, 1.        ],
       [0.00784314, 0.00784314, 0.00784314, 1.        ],
       .
       .
       .
```

So this array can be used to assign specific colors to each line, based on their fit.  And it assumes the higher numbers are better fits, and that you want better fits to be colored darker.

Note that before I had `color_gradient_divisions = [(1/len(fit))*i for i in range(len(fit))]`, which was incorrect as it evenly divides the color map into 25 pieces, not actually returning values corresponding to the fit.

The `cmap` is also passed to the colorbar when constructing it.  Often you can just call `plt.colorbar` to simply create one, but here `matplotlib` doesn't automatically know what to create a color bar for as the lines are separate and manually colored.  So instead, we create 2 `axes`, one for the plot and one for the colorbar (spacing them accordingly with the `gridspec_kw` argument), and then using `mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase` to make the colorbar (I also removed a `norm` argument b/c I don't think it is needed).

> **why have you used an underscore in the for loop?**

This is a pattern in Python, typically meaning "I'm not using this thing".  `enumerate` returns an iterator of tuples with the structure *(value index, value)*.  So `enumerate(fit)` returns `(0, 0.76458568)`, `(1, 0.15017328)`, etc (based on the data shown above).  I am only using the index (`i`) to get the corresponding position (and color) in `color_gradients` (`ax1.plot(x, y, c=color_gradients[i])`).  Even though the values from `fit` are being returned by `enumerate`, I am not using them, so I instead point them to `_`.  If I was using them within the loop, I would use a typical variable name instead.

`enumerate` is the encouraged way to loop over an iterable if you need to access both the count of the values and the values themselves.  People tend to use `for i in range(len(fit))` also to do this (which works fine!) but the further I've gone with Python the more I've seen people avoiding that.

This was a little bit of a confusing example; I set my loop to iterate over `fit` b/c I was conceptualizing "creating one graph for each value in `fit`".  But I could have just looped over `color_gradients` (`for c in color_gradients`) which might be more clear.

But in your real data, something like `enumerate` may be helpful if you are looping over multiple aligned arrays.  In my example, I just create new random data within each loop.  But you will likely want to have an array of fit values, an array of color values, an array (of series) of radii, and an array (of series) of masses, such that the *ith* element of each array corresponds to the same star.  You may be iterating over one array and want to access the same position in another (`zip` is used for this also).

---

*I'll leave this second answer here, even though it wasn't what OP was getting at:*

**You have one fit value for each point:**

Here, each pair of x,y coordinates has its own fit value:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.randint(100, size=25)
y = np.random.randint(100, size=25)
fit = np.random.rand(25)

plt.scatter(x, y, c=fit, cmap='binary')
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

---

**Note that with either approach, poorly fitting points or lines may be invisible**

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your response.  The second example you've provided is more similar to what I'd like to have, as each line corresponds to a single color.  So for a given line, each point on that line will be the same color, but each line will be a different color from the other lines.  I appreciate you including both examples!

In your second example, I just had a couple questions: how does ```fit``` play into the rest of the plot, and why have you used an underscore in the for loop?  I guess if you could just briefly describe what the code is doing, that would be so helpful.

Comment: But also you've already been a huge help!  I appreciate everything you've already replied with.

Comment: Np!  I've just updated to respond to your Qs, and to fix a couple things